# How to parse chunked HTTP content with Lua on nodemcu?

Tags: http, lua, nodemcu

I have script which coomunicates between nodemcu and my server. It works good on my localhost and is parsing response retrieved from my server when I send GET request. Problem is when I upload it all on my website where transfer encoding is chunked. I am not able to retrieve content, although request is legitimate and correct. Code is written in Lua and I am trying to work on my NodeMCU device.

```
conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    conn:on("connection",function(conn, payload)
    conn:send("GET /mypath/node.php?id=1&update"..
                " HTTP/1.1\r\n".. 
                "Host: www.mydomain.com\r\n"..
                "Accept: */*\r\n"..
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua;)"..
                "\r\n\r\n") 
            end)

    conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
        if string.find(payload, "UPDATE")~=nil then 
            node.restart()
        end

        conn:close()
        conn = nil

    end)
    conn:connect(80,"www.mydomain.com")
end
```

Just to repeat that this GET request works and is tested manualy and on localhost. Only problem is with chunked content, I don't know how to parse it.

Update: I managed to remove chunked encoding by changing HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/1.0, but still I have problem

using this code

```
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload)
        print(payload)
```

I get this response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 02:34:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9m226vr20r4baa634bagk8k2k3; path=/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Update 2.

I have just created one file http.php with text included "php". I have uploaded it to localhost and to my domain. Once I tried to access my localhost from nodemcu, and then to domain. Results were different

This is the request

```
conn:send("GET /"..s.path.."/http.php"..
                " HTTP/1.0\r\n".. 
                "Host: "..s.domain.."\r\n"..
                "Accept: */*\r\n"..
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua;)"..
                "\r\n\r\n") 
            end)
```

s.domain and s.path correcponds to different paths and domains on localhost and my domain

Result on domain

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 03:09:28 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

result on localhost

```
TTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 03:08:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.0.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.23
Content-Length: 3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

php
```

As you can see, localhost is showing content "php", and domain is showing only header. When I type some file which does not exists domain is showing me html code.

Comment: Do you mean the HTTP response' `Transfer-Encoding` header is `chunked`? When you test manually on localhost, what is the `Transfer-Encoding` header value? Is it also `chunked`?

Comment: What if you use the NodeMCU HTTP module?

Comment: I would check using HTTP module if I don't succeed with this. Problem is that it is working on one server, and not working on other. @shaochuancs I managed to turn chunked off by specifying http 1.0 in request. I have updated the question with additional info.

Comment: See how often the 'receive' event is fired. Only do `print(payload)` in the callback and don't close `conn`.

Comment: Just to mention again that all is working when I use localhost. It is working here too, but I don't see content of response, but only header. I tested it with HTTP module, and it is working like that, but I would like to figure out what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to put the chunks together. I'm wondering anyways, why your response from the server is missing the `Content-Length` header.

```
conn:on("receive", function(client, payload) 

  -- Inspired by https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver/blob/master/httpserver.lua
  -- Collect data packets until the size of HTTP body meets the Content-Length stated in header
  if payload:find("Content%-Length:") or bBodyMissing then
      if fullPayload then fullPayload = fullPayload .. payload else fullPayload = payload end
      if (tonumber(string.match(fullPayload, "%d+", fullPayload:find("Content%-Length:")+16)) > #fullPayload:sub(fullPayload:find("\r\n\r\n", 1, true)+4, #fullPayload)) then
          bBodyMissing = true
          return
      else
          payload = fullPayload
          fullPayload, bBodyMissing = nil
      end
  end

  if (bBodyMissing == nil) then
      local _, headerEnd = payload:find("\r\n\r\n")
      local body = payload:sub(headerEnd + 1)
      print (body)
  end
end)
```

Comment: Not sending `content-length` is definitely bad behavior on the server's part.